# Does QGIS Cloud support offsets for symbology?

Tags: qgis, symbology, qgis-cloud, offset

I used the offset settings for symbols in QGIS 2.18 but when uploaded to Cloud, the offsets don't seem to exist.

Can this setting be used in QGIS Cloud or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

There is one alternative that I know - [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/). Follow this steps:

1. Register in nextgis.com and [create your web GIS](https://my.nextgis.com/signup/?next=/webgis/).
2. Install [NextGIS Connect](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/) plugin in QGIS and add your web GIS into it.
3. [Publish](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/ngqgis_connect.html#creating-and-uploading-a-whole-qgis-project-to-web-gis) your current project as web map.
4. Profit

[image: Publish QGIS project into web GIS]

You can also see [documentation](http://docs.nextgis.com/index.html) or [video](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0U1GQHn7hbgYkUSnxYaDUQ).

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite useful. I'll give it a go and report back :)